# GridView RowUpdating - UpdateParameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble setting all of my Update Parameters. Most of the fields in my GridView are DataBound, but two of them are dropdown lists, one that has list items specified and one that pull from another data source. I would like to set their values as UpdateParameters to send to my Stored Procedure when the user clicks "Update" on the GridView. Although I'm not sure on how to go about doing that.

Here is the code I'm working with, the two dropdown lists are "ddlTransferLocation" and "ddlReconcileStatus":

DATA SOURCE

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="reconcileDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="GetReconcileItems" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand="UpdateReconcileItems" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ItemID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TransType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LocationID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Stat" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TransferLocation" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# ROW UPDATING

```
    protected void reconcileGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
      DropDownList ddlReconcileStatus = (DropDownList)reconcileGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlReconcileStatus");

      reconcileDataSource.UpdateParameters["Stat"].DefaultValue = ddlReconcileStatus.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

ASP.NET GRIDVIEW

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="reconcileUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="reconcileGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ItemID" DataSourceID="reconcileDataSource" OnRowUpdating="reconcileGrid_RowUpdating"  >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ReadOnly="true"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="last_known_location" HeaderText="Last Known Location" SortExpression="last_known_location" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# evalStatus(Eval("Stat")) %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate><EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReconcileStatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReconcileStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Allocated"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Transferred"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transfer Location" Visible="false" >
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransferLocation" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="ddlTransferLocationDataSource" DataTextField="Name" 
                                DataValueField="ID" Enabled="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource 
                                ID="ddlTransferLocationDataSource" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM [TransferLocation]">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="ItemID" ReadOnly="true" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `SqlDataSource.Updating` Event and do something like

```
DropDownList ddlReconcileStatus = (DropDownList)reconcileGrid.Rows[reconcileGrid.EditIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlReconcileStatus");
reconcileDataSource.UpdateParameters["Stat"].DefaultValue = ddlReconcileStatus.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Alright I'll give that a shot. Although I'm getting a no extension method found for "EditRowIndex"

Comment: Sorry it should be `EditIndex` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx

Comment: I see that it's getting the correct value and updating the parameter, but it never actually runs the stored procedure. I don't get any errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: After some testing it would seem that none of my bound fields are being associated with the UpdateParameters. Any reason this would be happening?